# looking for saml setting in docusign

Tags: single-sign-on, integration, saml-2.0, docusignapi

I am looking for SAML settings in docusign, using docusign developer demo account. Although, In

> Overview -> "create my organisation"

feature seems disable and SAML settings is no where available..

Please let me know how i can get iDp settings and SAML integration in Docusign?
whereas document says that it works for enterprise version ...can i get some free trial demo of saml integration.

I tried with support and live chat support but they are not able to reply properly and redirected me here

Answer (score 0):

There is a backend setting which DocuSign needs to enable to see "Overview -> Create Organization" option. This setting is not available for free. If you are buying the PROD DS Account then your DocuSign Account Manager will be able to help you in activating this setting in both PROD and Demo.